# How to select the first child node of a parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML structured like so:

```
<li class="mktFormReq mktField">
    <label>Industry</label>
    <span class="mktInput">
        <div class="jqTransformSelectWrapper" style="z-index: 9; width: 210px;">
            <div>
                <span style="width: 154px;">Consumer Packaged Goods</span>
                <a href="#" class="jqTransformSelectOpen"></a>
            </div>
            <ul style="width: 208px; display: none; visibility: visible;">
                <li style="">
                    <a href="#" index="0" class="">Industry*</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" index="1">Business Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" index="2" class="selected">Consumer Packaged Goods</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" index="3">Energy</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <select class="mktFormSelect mktFReq jqTransformHidden required" name="Download_Industry__c" id="Download_Industry__c" size="1" tabindex="8" style="">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Industry*</option>
                <option value="Business Services">Business Services</option>
                <option value="Consumer Packaged Goods">Consumer Packaged Goods</option>
                <option value="Energy">Energy</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <span class="mktFormMsg"></span>
    </span>
</li>
```

Here I have to pick the value in span of first div using jQuery. But when using the name or id attribute of the `select` element, i.e. using `#Download_Industry__c`, I have to pick the "Consumer Packaged Goods" value (the top `span` with the `style` attribute).

My approach is to pick the parent node of `select`, then select the first child, and then proceed. But I am unable to write syntax for it. I tried this way:

```
$('#Download_Country__c').parent().first().html();
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Where is `#Download_Country__c` element?

Comment: @JackBashford please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go up to the parent, then `find` the `span` you want:

```
$("#Download_Country__c").parent().find("div > span");
```

You could also use `siblings`:

```
$("#Download_Country__c").siblings(":first-child").find("span");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently selecting only the parent. (`$('#Download_Country__c').parent().first().html();` is the same as `$('#Download_Country__c').parent().html();`)

Try this for getting the first children:

```
$('#Download_Country__c').parent().children().first().html();
```